# Wordpress shortcode preview in tinyMCE

Tags: tinymce, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've written a shortcode and its functioning like it should. Now the hard part:

I would like to show the user a preview already in the tinyMCE editor. Loading CSS in the editor is not a problem for me, but i would love to know if it is possible to already process the shortcode within TinyMCE.

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't find an answer here, you should probably see how WordPress passes the [caption] tag - when you insert an image with a caption, you see the image and the caption beneath it, but it's actually just a shortcode.

Comment: thanks! I will look into that tomorrow when I don't get anything here. I was hoping there might be a filter or hook to run shortcodes in the backend :)

Comment: I took a quick look and it seems that you could probably add a custom TinyMCE plugin. See for example the code of the [wpGallery](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/wpgallery/editor_plugin_src.js) tinyMCE plugin. Basically it seems like tinyMCE has a couple of hooks that allow you to parse the content before it's displayed and before it's saved(on post update). Those hooks are added like so: `ed.onBeforeSetContent.add(function(ed, o) {}` and `ed.onPostProcess.add(function(ed, o) {}` . Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the code talk:
I'll put a code to add a visual icon for highlight content word(s) shortcode, and you can then implement any other shortcode you want with the same logic,

```
     class spot_shortcodes {

      function spot_shortcodes() 
{   

    add_action('init', array(&$this, 'init'));
}
function init(){

    // Enable shortcodes in text widgets
    add_filter( 'widget_text', 'do_shortcode' );

    // Fix for large posts, http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/8553
    @ini_set( 'pcre.backtrack_limit', 500000 );
    // init process for button control
    add_filter( 'tiny_mce_version', 'my_refresh_mce');

   // Add only in Rich Editor mode
   if ( get_user_option('rich_editing') == 'true') {
     add_filter('mce_buttons_3', array(&$this, 'register_highlight_button'));
   }    
}

    // Add your button plugin js code to tinyMCE
    // codex: wp_register_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer );
    wp_register_script( 'effects-highlight', SPOT_SHORTCODES_URL . '/js/jquery.effects.highlight.js', false ,SPOT_SHORTCODES_URL, true );

   function add_youtube_button() {

   // Don't bother doing this stuff if the current user lacks permissions
   if ( ! current_user_can('edit_posts') && ! current_user_can('edit_pages') )
     return;

   // Add only in Rich Editor mode
   if ( get_user_option('rich_editing') == 'true') {
     add_filter("mce_external_plugins", array(&$this, "add_youtube_tinymce_plugin"));
     add_filter('mce_buttons', array(&$this, 'register_highlight_button'));
   }
}

    // function to register you button to tinyMCE dashboard
    function register_highlight_button($buttons) {
   array_push($buttons, "|", 'highlight_button');
   return $buttons;
}

    function add_youtube_tinymce_plugin($plugin_array) {

    // your icon image(highlight.png) which will be displayed in the tinyMCE dashboard
    $plugin_array['highlight'] = SPOT_TINYMCE_URL . '/icons-lib-custom.js';

   return $plugin_array;
}

} // class end
// Finally make an object from your button
$spot_shortcodes = new spot_shortcodes();
```

Our js code for the highlight button option
make an dot js file put the followin code in it and put it in the tinyMCE plugin directory

```
// dont forget to change the paths
tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.highlight', {
    // creates control instances based on the control's id.
    // our button's id is "highlight_button"
    createControl : function(id, controlManageradel) {
        if (id == 'highlight_button') {
            // creates the button
            var button = controlManageradel.createButton('highlight', {
                title : 'Add a Hightlight Text', // title of the button
                image :spotShortcodes.plugin_folder +"/tinymce/images/highlight.png",  // path to the button's image
                onclick : function() {
                    // triggers the thickhighlight
                    var width = jQuery(window).width(), H = jQuery(window).height(), W = ( 720 < width ) ? 720 : width;
                    W = W - 80;
                    H = H - 84;
                    tb_show( 'Insert text box shortcode', '#TB_inline?width=' + W + '&height=' + H + '&inlineId=highlight-form' );
                }
            });
            return button;
        }
        return null;
    }
});

// registers the plugin. DON'T MISS THIS STEP!!!
tinymce.PluginManager.add('highlight', tinymce.plugins.highlight);
// executes this when the DOM is ready
jQuery(function(){
    // creates a form to be displayed everytime the button is clicked
    // you should achieve this using AJAX instead of direct html code like this
    var form = jQuery('<div id="highlight-form"><table id="highlight-table" class="form-table" style="text-align: left">\
         \
            \
        <tr>\
        <th><label class="title" for="highlight-bg">Highlight color</label></th>\
            <td><select name="bg" id="highlight-bg">\
                <option value="#f02d33">Red</option>\
                <option value="#b6bbbd">Grey</option>\
                <option value="#3e3c3c">Darkgrey</option>\
                <option value="#99cc33">Lightgreen</option>\
                <option value="#6c8c2d">Darkgreen</option>\
                <option value="#0f5ac6">Blue</option>\
                <option value="#3cbcf7">Cyan</option>\
                <option value="#9219f8">Purple</option>\
                <option value="#fcc016">Yellow</option>\
                <option value="#f65e0e">Orange</option>\
            </select><br />\
        <div class="info"><small>Select box type.</small></div></td>\
        </tr>\
        <tr>\
        <th><label class="title" for="highlight-contet">Conent</label></th>\
            <td><textarea rows="7"\ cols="45"name="content" id="highlight-content">hightlight text</textarea>\
                 <br />\
            <div><small>this text displayed in box.</small></div></td>\
        </tr>\
        </table>\
    <p class="submit">\
        <input type="button" id="highlight-submit" class="button-primary" value="Insert shortcode" name="submit" style=" margin: 10px 150px 50px; float:left;"/>\
    </p>\
    </div>');

    var table = form.find('table');
    form.appendTo('body').hide();

    // handles the click event of the submit button
    form.find('#highlight-submit').click(function(){
        // defines the options and their default values
        // again, this is not the most elegant way to do this
        // but well, this gets the job done nonetheless
        var options = { 
            'bg'     : '#f02d33',
            'content'  : 'hightlight text',
            };

        var shortcode = '[highlight ';

        for( var index in options) {
            var value = table.find('#highlight-' + index).val();

            // attaches the attribute to the shortcode only if it's different from the default value
            if ( value !== options[index] & index !== 'content')
                shortcode += ' ' + index + '="' + value + '"';
        }

        shortcode += ']'+ value + '[/highlight]'  

        // inserts the shortcode into the active editor
        tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', 0, shortcode);

        // closes Thickhighlight
        tb_remove();
    });
});
```

I hope this help, give me you feedback if you want any more explanation, thanks.

Comment: Your wp_register_script() line is throwing an error. I believe its outside of a function?

Comment: About what wp_register_script() you are talking? There is only one instance of it and it's not mind does it inner or outer, can you write down the displayed error, 
let me guess: 
1. do you give this constant SPOT_SHORTCODES_URL your customized value? 
2. can you replace the function with this & test this: 
define('SPOT_SHORTCODES_URL', 'Your/Custom/Path');
define('SPOT_SHORTCODES_VER', '0.1');
wp_register_script( 'effects-highlight', SPOT_SHORTCODES_URL . '/js/jquery.effects.highlight.js', false ,SPOT_SHORTCODES_VER, true );
Thanks, let me know if I can help you more, I'll be happy for this.

Comment: I'm not an expert in TiniMCE but I don't see anywhere in this code how to preview the highlight effect, which was the main question.

Comment: TinyMCE has it's own structure for any plugins you want to add to it, what we did in the above code steps was to follow/extend this predefine structure to add a button to the interface of the editor which contain the highlight effect functionallity.
Again as this all above steps is needed to add the highlight effect button to the TinyMCE editor interface.

you can also refere to the official site http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Tutorials:Creating_a_plugin

the extra here in my code is the integration with wordpress only.
hope this help.

Comment: @sergio is right. This doesn’t answer the question of how to show the results of the plugin in WordPress’s visual editor.

Comment: @sergio and Andy
to "show the results of the plugin in WordPress’s visual editor.", you need to:
1. write some php code which is a function to register you button to tinyMCE dashboard and apply the WP content filters and permissions (in theme functions.php or plugin code), this code in my answer 1st part.
2. JS code which will inject the new button(appearance look and feel) in the Wordpress rich editorEditor(it is tinymce[ this code will create tinymce plugin to add the button]), this is 2nd part of answer.
I implemented this code 5 years back and I have a themeforest theme including it.