# Wrapping shortcodes in temporary div wrappers for editing, then removing them prior to saving the content

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, tinymce

I'm working on a shortcodes preview filter where I wrap all of my shortcodes in CSS classed divs that are only intended to be viewed while the content is inside the tinyMCE editor.

The first challenge I have is how to strip out the wrapper divs from the markup prior to the document being saved.

The second challenge is how to reapply the wrappers each time a shortcode appears within the editor after a save.

I'm looking for an example of using jQuery to parse and filter TinyMCE editor contents on load and during save routines.

Comment: have you tried anything yet?

Comment: No, I'm researching it now. It appears that I'll need to use the tinymce plugin functionality to manipulate the tinymce dom. This answer appears to be closest > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687604/wordpress-shortcode-preview-in-tinymce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The first challenge I have is how to strip out the wrapper divs from
>   the markup prior to the document being saved.

This one is easy. Just give your wrapperDivs a special class

```
var ed = tinymce.get('my_editor_id');
$(ed.getBody()).find('div.my_special_class').each(function(){
    $(this).replaceWith(this.innerHTML);
});
```

> The second challenge is how to reapply the wrappers each time a
>   shortcode appears within the editor after a save.

This one is more difficult to answer. That depends on the difficulty to detect a shortcode.